# Solace application HA across regions

Tags: high-availability, solace

Currently intra-region we achieve HA (hot/hot) between applications by using exclusive queues to ensure 1 application is Active and the rest are standby.

How do I achieve the same thing across region when the appliances are linked via cspf neighbour links? As queues are local to an appliance the approach above doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible using your design of CSPF neighbors - they are meant for direct messages and not guaranteed.

Are you able to provide more details about your use case?

Solace can easily do active/standby across regions using [Data Center Replication](https://docs.solace.com/Features/Data-Center-Replication.htm).

Solace can also allow consumers to consume messages from the endpoints on both the active and standby regions by [Allowing Clients to Connect to Standby Sites](https://docs.solace.com/Features/Data-Center-Replication.htm#Allowing_Clients_to_Connect_to_Standby_Sites). However this means two consumers will be active - one on the active and one on the standby site.

Comment: I am reffering to application hot/hot, not the state of solace routers. 

I aware that cspf neighbour links are for direct messages, we use VPN bridges for guaranteed and in the future we will use DMR. This is not really about message flow, its a question about how do you provide a feature to application developers that gives you hot/hot ability in the applications across region. Anyway, had a meeting with solace and they say they don't natively support it.